# Enumerating items but with letters

Tags: enumerate, itemize

How do I do an "enumeration" of certain items with letters (a), (b), (c), etc.?

If I use

```
\begin{enumerate}   
\item ...   
\end{enumerate}
```

then I get numbers.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess there are several ways, but, in general I prefer the following. Because with this I can define my own labels. For e.g., a) b) c) or i) ii) ii) or 1) 2) 3) etc.

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

and then simply use it as follows.

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item ..
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

Here is the output. See [this](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for documentation.

[image]